# Using jQuery to trigger a change event in a Custom UL LI box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really need your help.

How can the code be modified below such that I can get a change event in my custom UL LI boxes. So for example, if the user were to make a change in the vegetables or fruits boxes, the code would alert back to the user that a change has been made?

Here is the complete markup below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
      * {
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-size: 9pt;
      }
      .select {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .select dd, .select dt, .select ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      .select dd {
        position: relative;
      }
      .select a, .select a:visited {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;
      }
      .select dt:hover, .select dd ul:hover {
        border-color: rgb(128,128,128);
      }
      .select dd ul li a:hover {
        background-color: rgb(112, 146, 190);
        color: #FFF;
      }
      .select dt {
        background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
        display: block;
        padding-right: 20px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        width: 180px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .select dt span {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        padding: 4px;
        height: 15px;
      }
      .select dd ul {
        background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        border-left: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        border-top: 0;
        display: none;
        left: 0px;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1px;
        width: auto;
        min-width: 200px;
        list-style: none;
      }
      .select dd ul li a {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        display: block;
      }
      .selected {
        background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
      }
      .header-list, .header-list:hover {
        padding-left: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".select dt").click(function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          var select = $(this).closest('.select');
          // close all other selects
          $('.select').not(select).find('ul').hide();

          select.find('ul').toggle();
          select.find("dt, dd ul").css('border-color', 'rgb(128,128,128)')

          select.find("dt, span, dd ul").css('background-color', 'rgb(255,255,196)')

        });

        $(".select dd ul li a").click(function(e) {
          var text = $(this).html();
          var select = $(this).closest('.select');

          if ((select.data('val') == 'multiple') && (e.ctrlKey)) {
            e.stopPropagation()
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            select.find('dt span').html("(" + select.find('a.selected').length + ")");

          }
          else {
            var text = $(this).html();
            select.find("dd a").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            select.find("dt span").html(text);
            //select.find("dt a").css("background-color", "");
            select.find("dd ul").hide();
          }
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function() {
          $(".select dd ul").hide();
          $(".select dt, .select dd ul").css('border-color', '');
        });

      });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body> 

    <dl class="select">
      <dt><span id="vegetables"></span></dt>
      <dd>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Carrots</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Celery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Brocoli</a></li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
    </dl>


    <dl class="select">
      <dt><span id="fruits"></span></dt>
      <dd>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bananas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
    </dl>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: the fact that u bind the click event to the custom selection seems to be correct approach. It is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use :

```
$(".select ul").on('click', function(e) {
    alert('change has been made');
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      * {
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-size: 9pt;
      }
      .select {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .select dd, .select dt, .select ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      .select dd {
        position: relative;
      }
      .select a, .select a:visited {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;
      }
      .select dt:hover, .select dd ul:hover {
        border-color: rgb(128,128,128);
      }
      .select dd ul li a:hover {
        background-color: rgb(112, 146, 190);
        color: #FFF;
      }
      .select dt {
        background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
        display: block;
        padding-right: 20px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        width: 180px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .select dt span {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        padding: 4px;
        height: 15px;
      }
      .select dd ul {
        background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        border-left: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        border-top: 0;
        display: none;
        left: 0px;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1px;
        width: auto;
        min-width: 200px;
        list-style: none;
      }
      .select dd ul li a {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        display: block;
      }
      .selected {
        background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
      }
      .header-list, .header-list:hover {
        padding-left: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".select ul").on('click', function(e) {
          alert('change has been made');
        });

        $(".select dt").click(function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          var select = $(this).closest('.select');
          // close all other selects
          $('.select').not(select).find('ul').hide();

          select.find('ul').toggle();
          select.find("dt, dd ul").css('border-color', 'rgb(128,128,128)')

          select.find("dt, span, dd ul").css('background-color', 'rgb(255,255,196)')

        });

        $(".select dd ul li a").click(function(e) {
          var text = $(this).html();
          var select = $(this).closest('.select');

          if ((select.data('val') == 'multiple') && (e.ctrlKey)) {
            e.stopPropagation()
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            select.find('dt span').html("(" + select.find('a.selected').length + ")");

          }
          else {
            var text = $(this).html();
            select.find("dd a").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            select.find("dt span").html(text);
            //select.find("dt a").css("background-color", "");
            select.find("dd ul").hide();
          }
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function() {
          $(".select dd ul").hide();
          $(".select dt, .select dd ul").css('border-color', '');
        });

      });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body> 

    <dl class="select">
      <dt><span id="vegetables"></span></dt>
      <dd>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Carrots</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Celery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Brocoli</a></li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
    </dl>


    <dl class="select">
      <dt><span id="fruits"></span></dt>
      <dd>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bananas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
    </dl>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/ 
according to the documentation, this will not work on his code. "This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements", and his is a custom tag.